# CustomListAdapter list items imitate each other

Tags: android, listview, custom-lists

I have read and tried several of the solutions to similar problems here on stack overflow, but none of them solved my problem. Here is the thing.

I have a `listview` which uses `CustomListAdapter`, each list item has a `progress bar`, a download button, title text and so on. When the download `button` is clicked a download operation is performed, and based on the result of the download(whether success or failure) the list item concerned is update(`UI` changes, such as if complete hide download button, update progress of the `progress bar` during download)

The `listview` displays four items at every given time

[image: first four items on display]

The problem is that whenever a `UI` change is made to an item say item 1(with index 0) the item 5 will also have the same changes, likewise if a change is made to item 3, the item 7 takes up those changes. In summary the item N+4 always imitates item N.

[image: changes of item zero, duplicated by item 5]

A look at my `getView()` will tell that I have checked all the known boxes.

```
 @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_mylibrarylist, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.name = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.name);
        holder.name.setTypeface(MainActivity.font_bahamas);

        holder.author = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.author);
        holder.author.setTypeface(MainActivity.font_bahamas);

        holder.worktype = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.worktype);
        holder.worktype.setTypeface(MainActivity.font_bahamas);

        holder.coverPic = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.coverPic);
        holder.downloadBt = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.downloadBt);
        holder.progressBar = (ProgressBar)view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar2);

        holder.menuBt = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.menuBt);

        holder.position =  position;

        view.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

    }

    if(holder.position == position)   {
        setValuesForListItemViews(holder, position, view);
    }
    return view;
}
```

The method to set each of the list items..

```
private void setValuesForListItemViews(ViewHolder holder, int position, View view) {

    if (!data.isEmpty()) {
        // set the list item elements here
        final CreativeWork creativeWork = data.get(position);

        holder.name.setText(creativeWork.getName().toLowerCase());
        holder.author.setText("by " + creativeWork.getOriginal_authors().toLowerCase());
        holder.worktype.setText(creativeWork.getWork_type().toLowerCase());

        Drawable draw = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.custom_progressbar2);
        holder.progressBar.setProgressDrawable(draw);
        holder.progressBar.setMax(100);
        holder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        holder.menuBt.setOnClickListener(new OnItemClickedListener(view, position, 1, creativeWork, holder.progressBar, holder.downloadBt));
        holder.menuBt.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(new MContextMenuListener(creativeWork, holder.progressBar, holder.downloadBt, false));


        //load image url
        ImageLoader2 imgLoader12 = new ImageLoader2(activity);
        imgLoader12.DisplayImage(creativeWork.getName(), R.drawable.downloads, holder.downloadBt);

        ImageLoader imgLoader = new ImageLoader(activity);
        imgLoader.DisplayImage(SLService.END_POINT + creativeWork.getImage_url(), R.drawable.soul_lounge, holder.coverPic);

        //check if file already exist and switch off download button
        DBHelper helper = new DBHelper(activity);
        CreativeWork cw = helper.getCreativeWork(creativeWork);

        if (cw != null) {
            File file = new File(cw.getFilePath());
            if (file.exists()) {
                holder.menuBt.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(new MContextMenuListener(creativeWork, holder.progressBar, holder.downloadBt, true));

                //check if the file download was complete
                if (cw != null) {
                    if (cw.getFileSize() > file.length()) {
                        holder.progressBar.setProgressDrawable(activity.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.custom_progressbar3));

                        ImageLoader2 imgLoader2 = new ImageLoader2(activity);
                        imgLoader2.DisplayImage(cw.getName(), R.drawable.restart, holder.downloadBt);

                        holder.progressBar.setProgress((int) ((file.length() * 100) / cw.getFileSize()));
                        holder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    } else {
                        holder.downloadBt.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        holder.downloadBt.setOnClickListener(new OnItemClickedListener(view, position, creativeWork, holder.progressBar, holder.downloadBt, 0));
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post code of setting view.[First four elements and next loop]

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to solve this is adding some extra fields to your model class whose list you are passing to your adapter.

like

```
boolean showDownloadButton; //default is true
int progress;// default is 0
```

So when user clicks on download button (or any other desired event) change the `boolean` value of `showDownloadButton` to false for model object at the given position and call `adapter.notifyDatasetChanged()` and manage the button visibility accordingly in your adapter.

and do make sure to add both visible and gone condition for the view aswell

```
if(modelList.get(position).getShowDownloadButton())
{
  btnDownload.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
}
else
{
  btnDownload.setVisibility(View.GONE)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nitesh's answer is right apart from that there is another way to do if you don't want to create Model class

Use setId and getId with position to identify unique row and assign that id to progressbar for the solution